# How to access docx default style

Tags: c#, openxml, office-interop, openxml-sdk

I've been trying to get all the docx's document content and information about each run/paragraph. So far I've managed to get style information from run/paragraph properties.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, false))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
            IEnumerable<Paragraph> paragraphs = mainPart.Document.Body.OfType<Paragraph>();
            foreach (Paragraph paragraph in paragraphs)
            {
                string text = paragraph.InnerText;

                IEnumerable<Run> runs = paragraph.Descendants<Run>();
                foreach (Run run in runs)
                {
                    string runText = run.InnerText;
                    RunProperties properties = run.RunProperties;
                    string fontsize = properties.FontSize.Val;
                    string fontsize2 = properties.FontSizeComplexScript.Val;
                    string fontaname = properties.RunFonts.HighAnsi;
                }
            }
        }
```

but this works only then, when text's format (style) is not default. In other words, `properties != null` and members inside are not `null`. So far I see only one way - to get style.xml formation content. Searches round the Internet gave me no clues. So, how can I access style.xml or get default font name, font size, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

to get the default style using OpenXML, you could use the following snippet:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true))
{

   DocDefaults defaults = doc.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart.Styles.Descendants<DocDefaults>().FirstOrDefault();
   //get the font size
   string fontSize = defaults.RunPropertiesDefault.RunPropertiesBaseStyle.FontSize.Val;
   //get the font prob. (Ascii, HAnsi, ComplexScript,...etc)
   RunFonts runFont = defaults.RunPropertiesDefault.RunPropertiesBaseStyle.RunFonts;

}
```

As for themes, you could get the major and minor fonts using the following:

```
var latineMajorFont = doc.MainDocumentPart.ThemePart.Theme.ThemeElements.FontScheme.MajorFont.LatinFont;
var latinMinorFont = doc.MainDocumentPart.ThemePart.Theme.ThemeElements.FontScheme.MinorFont.LatinFont;
var complexMajorFont = doc.MainDocumentPart.ThemePart.Theme.ThemeElements.FontScheme.MajorFont.ComplexScriptFont;
var complextMinorFont = doc.MainDocumentPart.ThemePart.Theme.ThemeElements.FontScheme.MinorFont.ComplexScriptFont;
```

Answer (score 2):

The default paragraph style is the one in the styles part with @w:type="paragraph" and **@w:default="1"**

Notice that the styles part also usually contains something like:

```
  <w:docDefaults>
    <w:rPrDefault>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:eastAsiaTheme="minorEastAsia" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cstheme="minorBidi"/>
        <w:sz w:val="22"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
        <w:lang w:val="en-AU" w:eastAsia="ko-KR" w:bidi="ar-SA"/>
      </w:rPr>
    </w:rPrDefault>
    <w:pPrDefault>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:after="200" w:line="276" w:lineRule="auto"/>
      </w:pPr>
    </w:pPrDefault>
  </w:docDefaults>
```

Refer to the Open XML spec for further details.

Comment: I've looked at that already. Also been doing search about accessing styles, but all code and examples was how to create style in new document, not how to read it. Also can't find default font document is using, as far as I understand `<w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:eastAsiaTheme="minorEastAsia" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cstheme="minorBidi"/>` describes something like encode, not the font itself.

Comment: After setting documnet's formation to default, font became `Calibli`. In `FontScheme` one of default fonts is `Calibri`, which is under `<minorFont>` namespace. So, how to find out when to use `typeFace` from `minorFont` and when from `majorFont`?

Answer (score 2):

```
<<So, how to find out when to use typeFace from minorFont and when from majorFont?>>
```

majorFont is meant to be used with Headings (Heading 1, etc.) and minorFont with "normal text".